# Unit Test for Python Click Command Fails on macOS Due to Sandbox Path Difference

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing, path, click

I have a Python module that uses the Click library for command-line interfaces.

Assume the module defines a `foo` function that takes a file path as an argument and calls the `bar` function with the provided path.

Module code:

```
import click

def bar(src):
    print(src)

@click.command("test")
@click.argument("src", nargs=-1, type=click.Path(exists=True, resolve_path=True))
def foo(src):
    return bar(src)
```

Now, I'm trying to write a unit test for this module using unittest and click.testing.CliRunner on macOS. Here's my unit test code:

```
import os
import unittest
import click.testing
import tempfile
from unittest.mock import patch
import temp_module  # The module with the foo function

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
        self.temp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        self.downloads = os.path.join(self.temp, "downloads")
        os.mkdir(self.downloads)

        def runtime(*args):
            return self.runner.invoke(temp_module.foo, args=args)

        self.runtime = runtime

    def test_foo(self):
        with patch("temp_module.bar") as mock_bar:
            self.runtime(self.downloads)

        expected_src = (self.downloads,)
        mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(self.downloads)
```

However, when running the test, it fails with the following assertion error:

```
AssertionError: expected call not found.
Expected: bar(('/var/folders/.../downloads',))
Actual: bar(('/private/var/folders/.../downloads',))
```

After some investigation, I discovered that macOS sandboxing creates a private `/var` directory for each process, which effectively isolates the process from the system-wide `/var` directory. As a result, the file path returned by click.Path(resolve_path=True) in the foo function contains the `/private` prefix.

How can I fix this unit test to account for the difference in file paths caused by macOS sandboxing and ensure that the unit test will still work on different operating systems (i.e., not prefixing the `self.downloads` path myself)?